# is(':Visible') is not working in ASP.NET 4 /Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visible

I have an Asp.net Website with c#.

in HTML section I have both Video and Audio Player in different Panels. 
each time just one of them can be visible , I wrote this Code for them. 
forexample in Back Code in some Place :

c# code

```
 pnlAudioPlayer.Visible = true;
 pnlVideoPlayer.Visible = false;
```

HTML Code

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" Style="text-align: center; background-color:   #fff; width: 440px;>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlAudioPlayer" runat="server" Width="100%">
   ....
```

and in Js code I have this

```
   if ($('#pnlAudioPlayer').is(':Visible')) 
      alert("audio");
 else
     alert("audio invisible!!!");
```

but it doesnt work.I mean everytime it shows "audio invisible", and the same problem is with Video Player.
it seems is(':Visible') is not work here . whats the problem????(I used different versions of JQuery, not its v10.1)

Comment: Looks like you might be barking up the wrong tree: http://jsfiddle.net/9wzkev2e/ `:visible` tests whether the element that [consumes space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/). I don't know what that `.Visible = true;` does, but it appears your element is indeed not `:visible`.

Comment: but it works in another project. I had to check something in BackEndCode and then decide to make panel Visible or inVisible. I updated my post and it has related HTML Code now. and the "Audio Player" is shown in the page.

Comment: Use the browser's console to inspect the element and determine it's style properties. I can't tell you anything else because what I know about what you've provided works. The two lines at the top, I don't know what affect those have on the style properties of whatever element that ostensibly points to.

Comment: And note, posting the ASP.NET code is useless when debugging what's going on in the browser. You need to post the markup the *browser sees*, e.g., what's in the source or in the browser console's Element tab (after inspecting the element, you can copy the source from the top-most element). If you need help learning to use the console, see [Chrome's console tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

Comment: `pnlVideoPlayer.Visible = false;` will not render the control at all. `pnlAudioPlayer.Visible = true;` will render a `div`. Inspect the div element to check its style properties. Target the panel using `<%=pnlAudioPlayer.ClientID%>` in your javascript incase it is rendered with a prefix.

Comment: That would certainly be a problem.

Comment: luke2012: if Visible=false make panel not rendered , then all elements on it should not rendered too.i mean I have <audio id="AudioPlayer" ...></audio> inside "pnlAudioPlayer". then how can I check the visibility of panel in javascript? or if the <audio> is rendered ?

Comment: How can I check if an element is rendered in jQuery???     (document.getElementById("<%= pnlAudioPlayer.ClientID %>")) {...} is not working

Comment: @JaredFarrish : no display or similar property on inspecting found.....  <div id="cphBody_pnlAudioPlayer" style="width:100%;">
     <div style="position: relative; width: 440px;  height:226px;">......//some code/.... </div>
             <audio id="audioplayer" src="...mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" preload="none" style="width: 440px"></audio>
    this is the code after rendering                             
 </div>

Comment: @luke2012: also JaredFarrish Thanks Guys. with this Code, I could handle it .....>      if (document.getElementById('<%= pnlAudioPlayer.ClientID %>')) {...}    thanks alot for your helps

Answer (score -1):

Case sensitive perhaps?  try this:

```
.is(':visible')
```